# Restrict SFTP user to run only limited set of commands/action in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, sftp, sshd, restricted-shell

How to restrict SFTP users to run only limited set of commands/actions.

For users connected to shell there is a option to configure restricted shell. Once done user can run only allowed commands. e.g. `User1` can only execute `cat`, `touch`, `more`, `ls` commands.

But how to accomplish this for users not connected to shell (e.g. user connected to Linux via SFTP with WinSCP). For example, I need to restrict their actions to a *read* action or deny from using *delete* action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the SFTP server in read-only mode using [`-R` switch](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp-server#R):

```
Match user Users1
    Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -R
```

---

Or you can restrict individual operations using [`-P` switch](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp-server#P).

For example, to disable *deleting*, you can do:

```
Match user Users1
    Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -P remove,rmdir
```

*(Though note this won't prevent user from overwriting existing files)*